# What is the font-family for the name of an algorithm

Tags: fonts

How to type something like
[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `\textsc`? That doesn't answer the problem of the font *family*.

Comment: @Bernard: In my opinion, that's a misunderstanding of the terminalogy.

Comment: @Werner: Probably. The font family itself is clearly not Computer Modern.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I concur that this should be `\textsc{Enqueue}`. On the other hand I don't think there is a standard for algorithm name typesetting.